# how to set the radius of a shape to bigger or smaller by pressing buttons in javascript/svg

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

Hi I have the following code and I want to be able to change the radius of a circle by pressing a button I dont know what to use after style. in the
document.getElementById("circle1").style.r="10"; part of the code

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function circle() {
        document.getElementById("circle").style.r="50";
}

    function circle1() {
        document.getElementById("circle1").style.r="10";

} 


    </script>


    </head>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="svg" >
     <circle id = "circle" cx = "100" cy = "800" r = "30" stroke="blue" stroke-width = "2" fill = "black"/>
     <circle id = "circle1" cx = "20" cy = "500" r = "30" stroke="blue" stroke-width = "2" fill = "black"/>
    </svg>
    <body>
    Set size of circles
    <input type="button" onclick="circle()" value="big" />
    <input type="button" onclick="circle1()" value="small" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted by [pp19dd, in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10181587/82548), the key is `setAttribute()`, but as it seems you want to increase/decrease the `r` attribute of the `circle` elements (and not simply *set* it to a particular value), you'll need to use `getAttribute()` as well.

This is a fairly simple function and implementation that, I think, does what you wanted:

```
function circle(delta){
    if (!delta){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var e = document.querySelectorAll('circle[id^=circle]'),
            changeBy = 10;
        if (delta == 'big'){
            e[0].setAttribute('r',parseInt(e[0].getAttribute('r'),10) + changeBy);
            e[1].setAttribute('r',parseInt(e[1].getAttribute('r'),10) + changeBy);
        }
        else if (delta == 'small'){
            e[0].setAttribute('r',parseInt(e[0].getAttribute('r'),10) - changeBy);
            e[1].setAttribute('r',parseInt(e[1].getAttribute('r'),10) - changeBy);
        }
    }
}

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    buttons = [];

for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type == 'button') {
        inputs[i].onclick = function(){
            circle(this.value);
        }
    }
}
```

​​[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QkAB5/).

Note that I've not implemented any checks for invalid negative values for the circle's `r` attribute. You may want to add that yourself.

And I used `document.querySelectorAll()` for simplicity (rather than two explicit calls to `document.getElementById()`). This *will* cause [problems in Internet Explorer](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t13), though I'm unsure as to how well implemented SVG *is* in Internet Explorer, so it might not make things any worse.

Having said all that, though, it seems that IE 9 implements the demo perfectly. Which surprises me no end..! IE 8, and lower, though, I'm unable to say.

References:

- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll).
- [`element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute).
- [`element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: thanks for your help I want to get all of the code into html but it doesnt work in http://jsfiddle.net/QkAB5/1/ or in firefox can you tell me where I am going wrong please by looking at the demo

Comment: You forgot that browsers execute JavaScript when it encounters JavaScript, as it processes/renders the document. As none of the elements exist in the DOM at that point it can't assign the event-handlers, and it doesn't come back to look again once it finishes rendering the document. So, to avoid that problem, use [`window.onload = function() { /* all that other stuff in here */ };`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QkAB5/2/), which effectively defers the binding/execution until after the `window.onload` event occurs, so the elements and the DOM is constructed and available at this point.

Comment: You're very welcome! I wasn't trying to push you to an accept, I just wondered if it was working or if you needed more help with it. But thank you, and I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Comment: no probs and thank you sorry to be a pain quick question if I wanted to do the same say for a rectangle would the setattribute and get attribute be changed to either height or width and set id to the rectangle? and would there be any other changes?

Comment: I think that should do it, I haven't really worked with SVG before this question, but I'd imagine that you might have to consider repositioning the element, depending on whether its initial position is set to the centre-point of the element or a corner.

Comment: yeah thats right just tried it and at the moment it increases in size to the right and decreases to the left of the screen

Answer (score 4):

To alter the attribute, use the **setAttribute()** function:

```
function circle() {
    document.getElementById("circle").setAttribute('r', "50" );
}

function circle1() {
    document.getElementById("circle1").setAttribute('r', "50" );
}
```

See this jsfiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/dGmxh/2/

Comment: Alternatively, consider using RaphaelJS- for cross-browser compatibility and other doodads. See http://jsfiddle.net/dGmxh/3/

Answer (score 0):

The function definitions in the head have the same name, and they don't seem to have closing brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use the svg.js library, which makes lots of these SVG tasks more friendly in a way similar to how jQuery makes JavaScript friendlier. Anyway, in svg.js, you create a circle of radius 1 and then change its radius to 5 like so:

```
var circ = draw.circle(1).attr({ cx: 10, cy: 10, fill: 'none', stroke: 'yellow', 'stroke-width': 2 });
circ.attr({ rx: 5, ry: 5 });
```

If you want to animate the change of the radius in 500ms, just add the animate() method like so

```
circ.animate(500).attr({ rx: 5, ry: 5 });
```

You can simply execute the second line of the code (the one changing the radius) in the onclick() javascript method.

Answer (score -1):

Use onClick

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: I think the question was regarding the programmatic modification of SVG radii, rather than how to capture the click event `:)`.